# not getting output from receive job

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, start-job, powershell-jobs

The variable $var is blank when I run this script:

```
function FOO { write-output "HEY" }

$var = Start-Job -ScriptBlock { ${function:FOO} } | Wait-Job | Receive-Job

$var
```

How do I get output from receive-job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Start-Job` spawns a new PowerShell instance in the background and as such has no knowledge of your function `FOO` which is defined in your initial instance

There is an additional parameter `InitializationScript` which is called upfront executing your script block in the new instance which you can use to define `FOO` like so

```
$var = Start-Job -InitializationScript { function FOO { write-output "HEY" } } -ScriptBlock ...
```

BTW: I guess you want to execute the function instead of getting the function object itself so you may want to change your script block to this

```
-ScriptBlock { FOO }
```

Comment: I'm confused, I have a bunch of functions in separate files dot sourced in one main file how would I call the dot sourced functions in the main file?

Comment: You will have to import / dot-source the necessary functions again in that job .e.g via the init script block as shown above

Comment: Ah I'll try that, is there a difference between dot sourcing and doing ${function:myfunc} inside the script block?

Comment: Yeah that is quite different - `${function:myfunc}`actually gets you the function object (script block) of `myfunc` itself whereas dot-sourcing a script file essentially processes the script file's contents in your scope which may define - among others - the function `myfunc`. So both are fundamentally different things - maybe I also misunderstood your question :)