# How do I import functions in separate files into a main file and run them as jobs?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, jobs, job-scheduling

I already asked a somewhat related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39136708/not-getting-output-from-receive-job).

I have a bunch of functions in separate files dot sourced in one main file how would I call those function in the main file as jobs?

Here is func1.ps1:

```
function FOO { write-output "HEY" }
```

Here is func2.ps1:

```
function FOO2 { write-output "HEY2" }
```

Here is testjobsMain.ps1

```
$Functions = {
    . .\func1.ps1
    . .\func2.ps1
}

$var = Start-Job -InitializationScript $Functions -ScriptBlock { FOO } | Wait-Job | Receive-Job

$var
```

When I run testjobsMain.ps1 I get this error:

```
. : The term '.\func1.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:2 char:4
+     . .\func1.ps1
+       ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (.\func1.ps1:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

. : The term '.\func2.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:3 char:4
+     . .\func2.ps1
+       ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (.\func2.ps1:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Running startup script threw an error: The term '.\func2.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again..
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (localhost:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PSSessionStateBroken
```

Comment: Have you tried with full (not relative) paths? That is: `. c:\func1.ps1`

Comment: Damn that was all it was. Is there a way I can use the relative path of the function files? They will all be in the same folder.

Comment: See my answer below. I have got a lot of pain with PS relative/absolute paths, believe me.

Comment: [Here](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Pester/3.3.14/Content/Pester.psm1) is a nice example of dotsourcing multiple files at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolute paths worked for me:

```
$Functions = {
    . c:\foo.ps1
}
$var = Start-Job -InitializationScript $Functions -ScriptBlock { FOO } | Wait-Job | Receive-Job
$var
```

If needed, in testjobsMain.ps1 you can substitute relative paths with absolute by using `$PSScriptRoot` automatic variable. For instance:

```
$Functions = [scriptblock]::Create(" . $PSScriptRoot\foo.ps1 `n . $PSScriptRoot\bar.ps1 `n")
```